# invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘struct coada’)

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create a list of threads that would be locked and executed in the order of the list. here is the code( it's a busy wait simulation I have for a course)

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include<pthread.h>
# include<stdlib.h>

# define NKIDS  10

pthread_mutex_t mutx;

struct kidrec {
    int data;
    pthread_t id;
};

struct coada {
    struct kidrec th;
    struct coada *next;
};

void *copilfunc(void*p)
{
    int *ip=(int*)p;
    int tmp;
    int v;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutx);
    tmp=v; v=*ip;
    printf(" We are at thread %d \n",v);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutx);
}

int main(){
    struct kidrec kids[NKIDS];
    struct coada c[NKIDS];
    int m;
    for(m=0;m<NKIDS;m++){
        kids[m].data=m;
        pthread_create(&kids[m].id,NULL,copilfunc,&kids[m].data);
        c[m].th=kids[m];
        if(m>0) c[m-1]->next=c[m];
        if(m==NKIDS) c[NKIDS]->next=c[0];
    }
    for(m=0;m<NKIDS;m++)
        pthread_join(c[m].th.id,NULL);
}
```

Comment: What more do you need than the compiler error? You can't use `->` on a struct, only on a pointer to a struct.

Comment: I used the struct coada *next; so next points to another struct. So i want to link c[m-1] which is a struct to c[m] (another struct)

Answer (score 1):

The variable `c[]` is an array of `struct coada`, not `struct coada *`.

So the expression `c[m-1]` is a `struct coada`, and you access its fields with `.`.

Thus, it should be:

```
c[m - 1].next = &c[m];
```

It doesn't matter that `next` is a pointer, the period is for accessing the `struct`-typed value on its left. Also note that you need to take the address of the array element, thus the `&` on the right.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access an attribute on an array of a struct using -> which is an access operator used for pointers (non-arrays)... 
Try using

```
c[i].next = &c[j]
```

instead of

```
c[i]->next = c[j]
```

;)